# Problema com Font Awesome em Select Box

Tags: html, css

Olá, estou aprendendo sobre HTML/CSS e atualmente estou tentando clonar a página da Netflix pra fins educativos. Porém, estou enfrentando um problema logo no header onde eu não consigo adicionar um determinado ícone usando Font-Awesome dentro de um select.

Quero que fique assim:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUCZl.png

Mas o ícone não funciona de jeito nenhum.

```css
* {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        font-size: 62.3%;
        background: black;
        color: white;
    }
    
    header { 
        padding-top: 2em;
    }
    
    .menu {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        
    }
    
    
    
    .logo img {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        align-items: center;
        left: 25px;
        width: 10rem;
        
    }
    
    .menu-buttons {
        display: flex;
        margin-right: 3rem;
        padding-top: 0.8rem;
    }
    
    .menu-buttons select {
        border: 1px solid white;
        font-size: 0.998rem;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 3%;
        margin-right: 1.5rem;
        padding-right: 1rem;
      
    }
    
    .menu-buttons .entrar {
        font-size: 0.998rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 3%;
        background-color: red;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding-left: 1rem;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
        <nav class="menu">
            <div class="logo">
                <img
                    src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PrathameshDhande22/Neflix-Clone/main/Images/netflix%20log.png">
            </div>
            <div class="menu-buttons">
                <select><i class="fa-solid fa-globe fa-sm"></i>
                    <option value="pt-BR" selected>Português</option>
                    <option value="en-BR">English</option>
                </select>
                <button class="entrar">Entrar</button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Se puderem analisar a semântica disso tudo e dizer como está para que eu melhore, ficarei agradecido também. Ás vezes tenho a sensação de tá usando algo de maneira errada.

Answer (score -3):

A especificação HTML não permite colocar tags dentro de um select. O que podes fazer é colocar o ícon antes do select e dar uma margem negativa para sobrepôr.

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
<select id="select-language">
    <option value="pt-BR" selected>Português</option>
    <option value="en-BR">English</option>
</select>

.menu-buttons select {
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.fa-globe {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```